# How to select 2 words on pressing Control+Right in textbox (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, keydown

I have textbox in WPF with a string like this **Good morning Mr President**. My caret is at the beginning of string. When I press Control + Right, the caret moves to before **morning** but I want to make it recall itself. So when I presss Control + Right, the caret moves from before **Good** to before **Mr** instead.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use `KeyPress` instead. :-)

Comment: Do you want to select 2 words always or only in this scenario?

Comment: @vishakh369: I just want this happen when using Ctrl+Right, I use PreviewKeyDown event, no KeyPress event in WPF. There is no caret index in C#.

Comment: I have found a solution on how to do this. But it might be bit tough to implement practically. Anyways check it and let me know if there are any doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. +1 for that.

But I am afraid, there is no default way that when you press **Ctrl+Right**, the text box selects 2 words.

The only possible solution is to handle the **KeyDown** or **PreviewKeyDown** event since it is required for non character keys and find the white space index and move it to the second white space using below code

```
textBoxName.Select(0, textBoxToHighlight.Text.Length);
```

This is the only possible solution you could work with. In other languages like for Japanese you could move it manually to the first white space using conditional statements. maybe you need to define it for every language which is different  from English.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know how to move to first white space because Japanese doesn't have white space. Textbox can automatically recognize next word to stop the caret.

Comment: Unless you have some common **first letter** or something, how can you find each word. Consider your self as a person who doesn't know japanese. Is it possible for you to separate Japanese words from a sentence. Same logic here also. Consider the CLR as such a person. For english he could easily identify with space. But if such a condition is not there, then it's quite impossible to achieve such a behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Simple cake recipe to what you are trying to achieve

```
while key is pressed:
    move the caret to the the next word.
end while
```

Where key would be `Ctrl + right arrow`. To achieve this kind of behavior have a look at the [KeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event.

Comment: The problem is how to move the caret to the next word. Specifically, I am processing Japanese, so I cannot find white space to detect next word. That is why I want to press key (Ctrl+Right) one time but I need it to activate 2 times.

Comment: In _Japanese_, what _symbol_ identifies the next word? In your example you used english that's why I assumed english.

Comment: I think textbox can automatically recognize word boundary. If I type "日本の医療政策の概要と基本情報" and press control+right, it becomes something like this "日本 の 医療 政策 の 概要 と 基本 情報". Each white space is where the caret stops and I want to get that (like next stop of current caret index).